# wordpress on plesk server not serving .svg and .otf and .ttf font files 404 error

Tags: php, wordpress, svg

I'm developing a site for a client and basically I'm having trouble serving the .svg and font files.

I built the site using wordpress and the ACF plugin.  I just attached a plugin that should let me upload SVGs, and it let me 'upload' them but when I load the page the console reads the error:
GET http://appyfizz.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/twitter_white.svg 404 (Not Found)

basically I'm getting a 404 error for all of these file types no matter whether they're stored in the images directory or whether I'm uploading them.

Please help!  I think the client is getting impatient!

Comment: Add some code, how are you giving the src/path for the resources? Posting this can help you someone help you.

Comment: appyfizz.com -- if you check the console you'll see the errors

Comment: I've tried using ACF <?php the_field("twitter_black", 65) ?> as well as <?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/insta_white.svg"  -- this worked on my bluehost server

Answer (score 0):

Check file permissions. For all the files they should be 644 and folders 755. It happened to me once and there was an issue with permissions.

Comment: Cool I'll check it out.  Is it something I change on the server or in the wordpress files?

Comment: You can change it via file manager, ftp client or some server side file manager. You can certainly do it via CLI also but I think you can try doing it using FTP client.

Comment: I have access to the server-- didn't see anything about 644 or 755, but the folders and files seemed to all have read + write access

Comment: Is it possible that the database is too old to be saving these properly?

Comment: it's mySQL 5.1 whereas I developed on mySQL 5.5 so my import didn't work because of utf8mb4 on my server vs utf8 on the client serer

Comment: Database does not have to do anything with it unless it is outputting wrong file url's. Check context menu for file permissions. Check your ftp client documentation for setting file permissions.